# How to bind this collection to my listbox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How do i wrap a collection of wrapped class. I have a property in my View Model which is of type

```
AsyncVirtualizingCollection<Item> ItemValues{get;set;}
```

Where Wrapper is a generic type

```
Wrapper<T>
```

Of Item class. Basically I am trying to do a data Virtualization from this [link](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=378)

Item is a simple class containing three properties (Caption, Key and IsSelected (Implements INotifyPropertyChanged)

I need to bind that to a List Box (with checkboxes). I have this templete and am binding this way

Templete :

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                        <Border Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Background="{x:Null}">
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <Grid Width="auto" x:Name="grid1">
                                        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding Caption}" 
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                  Foreground="#FF3F3F3F" Background="{x:Null}"
                                                  FontSize="13" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"
                                                  ClickMode="Release">
                                            <CheckBox.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,2,0,2" />
                                                </Style>
                                            </CheckBox.Style>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And the Main Listbox is like this :

```
<Grid x:Name="gridMain" Height="auto" Width="auto" Background="White">

        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemValues}"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                 Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}" 
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                 VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"  
                 Background="{x:Null}" 
                 BorderBrush="Transparent">
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

On running this it only shows the Checboxes and not the Caption. I know i am doing something wrong here in binding.

If i remove the style from the list box it shows me list of strings ".Wrapper`1[.Item]"

Any suggestions what could be missing here ?

Comment: I found that using this works

    Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Data.Caption}"

Thanks..
Shankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using this works

```
Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Data.Caption}"
```

Thanks